# Jquery Clone and Increase attri Id

Tags: jquery, clone

How can I increase the number of id after I clone. Ex: first row id 1 and last row id 2. when I click the button one, so the id the first the same 1 and second is 2 and the last clone is 3. Any solution for this? Thanks in advance guys.

```
<table>
<tr id="1">
    <td><label>contact name</label></td>
    <td>
        <select>
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
        </select>

    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="2">
    <td><label>contact name</label></td>
    <td>
        <select>
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
        </select>

    </td>
</tr>
```

```
$('.submit').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault()
var s = $('table tr:last-child);
s.clone(true).insertAfter(s);
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.submit').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var s = $('table tr:last-child');
    var i = parseInt(s.attr("id"), 10) + 1;
    s.clone(true).insertAfter(s).attr("id", i);
});
```

This should do it. It parses the number of the cloned row and the increments it. Once the row is cloned and inserted, it sets to `id` attribute of that row to the updated number. An example can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/3Gnvs/, but it uses psuedo code instead of your exact code.

Comment: Use radix for parseInt with base 10. `parseInt(s.attr("id"), 10)` . https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: @PSL Thank you, I added that to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use that:  [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RzznT/)

```
$('.submit').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    var s = $('table tr:last');
    s.clone(true).insertAfter(s).get(0).id = $('table tr').length;
})
```

Comment: can you please explain your code about .get(0).id = $('table tr').length. Thanks

Comment: get(0) will return the dom node (same behaviour than [0]) then you can use property id instead of using attribute method on jquery object.Just a habit i got... BTW, PSL's answer is better than the one you choose...